# Why is style.display's value undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What could be a reason for an element's `style.display` returning the value `undefined`?

In my Javascript, I have an if statement checking

```
if (document.getElementById("myModal").style.display != 'none'){ 
    console.log("The pop up is visible.");
    do something
}
```

In my CSS, I have `myModal` set to `display: none;`

`myModal` is a pop up form that is accessed through click.

I moved my `<script>` for the js file to the bottom of the HTML, doesn't this ensure that my DOM is fully loaded before the javascript is run? However, the `console.log` displays as soon as the page is loaded even though the conditional is not met (i.e. the pop up is currently not visible).

Not sure if the Leaflet API has anything to do with this?

Comment: Fixed, sorry bout that.

Comment: @IsabelInc Elements before the `<script>` tag are guaranteed to be ready before the script executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in your CSS stylesheets has little to do with the style property of your element. The style property only includes inline styles. Notice how in this code the first div has an empty `style.display`, even though it is `display: none` because of the stylesheet; only the second and third div have `style.display` properties set to anything:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll( 'div' );
[].forEach.call( divs, div => document.body.innerHTML += div.style.display + '<br>' );
```

```css
div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Divs:</h2>

<div>One</div>
<div style="display:none;">Two</div>
<div style="display:block;">Three</div>

<h2>Styles:</h2>
```

If you want to get the computed style of an element, considering all stylesheets and inline styles, you can use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Or you can just use jQuery:

```
if ( $('#myModal').is(':visible') ) {
    console.log("The pop up is visible.");
}
```

Comment: thanks, makes sense! would you also happen to know why the if statement may not run at all? so I changed it to set the display to block before the `if` and then checked if `display == 'block'` but it doesn't run altogether now

Comment: @ToniAu Check your browser's console for errors. If JavaScript encounters an error that isn't inside a `try { }` block of a `try .. catch` statement the script just immediately stops and no further lines are executed.